# Check if supplied datetime value lies between a certain time interval

Tags: php, mysql

***Scenario***

**UDPATE**

Please ignore the commented section. After thinking for an alternative, I came up with this:

Let's say I have

```
$date = '2012-10-03 13:00:00'
```

The time interval range is

```
2012-10-03 12:00:00 to 2012-10-03 14:00:00
```

Now `$date` falls between the time range mentioned above. Any ideas on how to compare a date time with a range of date time? I've come across functions which compare either just date or just time but not both at the same time. Any help much appreciated.

```
/*I'm building a school timetable and want to make sure that a room cannot be assigned to two different periods if it is already occupied. I have datetime values of **`2012-10-03 13:00:00`** (the start time of a period. Let's call it **abc** for reference) and **`2012-10-03 13:30:00`** (the end time of a period. Let's call it **xyz** for reference). 

My database table contains columns for room number assigned for a period and the start and end time of that period. Something like this:

    room_no | start_time          | end_time
       5      2012-10-03 13:00:00   2012-10-03 14:30:00

This means for October 3, 2012 room 5 is occupied between 1pm and 2:30pm. So the datetime values that I have (abc & xyz) will have to be assigned to a room other than 5.

I'm at a loss of ideas on how to go about validating this scenario, i.e. make sure that the period with time interval between abc & xyz cannot be assigned room number 5.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

PS : I'm not asking for code. I'm looking for ideas on how to proceed with the issue at hand. Also, is there a way a query can be build to return a row if `abc` or `xyz` lie between `start_time` and `end_time` as that would be great and reduce a lot of workload. I could simply use the number of rows returned to validate (if greater than 0, then get the room number and exclude it from the result)*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(StartTime - BookingTime < 0 && BookingTime - EndTime < 0)
{
  // Booking time is already taken
}
```

You can do this in SQL with TIMEDIFF().

Comment: So in my case, bookingtime will be the time referenced by `abc`?

Comment: My example was to show if a specified time was taken. So if there was a booking between 3pm and 5pm and booking time was 4pm, it would enter that if statement. If you were validating a new request, you would want to compare the new starting booking time and end booking time, to make sure it doesn't overlap in anyway.

Comment: But would this not mean looping through each record of the table to get the starttime and endtime for each row? Wouldn't this be costly if there are say 300+ rows?

Comment: Not if you build the query correctly. For example, to select all room_no where the requested booking time ISN'T availabe: `SELECT room_no FROM Table WHERE TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(start_time, $InputStartTime) > 0 AND TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF($InputEndTime, end_time) > 0;`

Comment: I made a mistake and it's too late to edit: `SELECT room_no FROM Table WHERE TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(start_time, $InputStartTime)) < 0 AND TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF($InputEndTime, end_time)) < 0;` This only checks start time against start time and end time against end time... Really you want to check both against both.

Comment: Np. So if I got this right, if a row is returned it means another room will have to be assigned?

Comment: If you want to check for a specific room, you can update the query to have "AND room_no = $InputRoomNo" on the end. Then yes, if a value is returned the room is already booked.

Comment: Hmm..I can't supply the query with a room number. I'm showing a dropdown with the list of rooms available to the user so that he can choose the room from that dropdown.  So I can't add the 'AND' clause to the query since I won't know which room the user will select.

Comment: Ah right, so you a list of available rooms for the given time slot. I assume you have a "rooms table" that has a list of all rooms and their room numbers. A query for this is possible but it becomes harder as it involves another level of complexity as you'll require JOINS. It depends on how much SQL you know. You could use the query I supplied without the room_no and instead manually check the list of rooms and remove the ones returned from the query.

Comment: Yes. You hit the bullseye. I only want to show the list of available rooms for the given time slot. And yes I've a rooms table. Frankly speaking, I'm very good in PHP but MySql is a sore subject for me. Building logical queries is the only weakpoint that I want to get rid of but I guess I'll have to put in a lot of effort to get the hang of complex queries involving joins and what not. Giving you +1 for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on something similar and perhaps an easier way to code it would not be using times but timeslots? The way I thought of doing it was a table bookings (date, slot ids, room)  table slots (with maybe slot ID and TIME) and per booking use a certain amount of slots.. then when you look for when the room is available it shows you per date what slots are free.. Just an idea.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I'm hoping to avoid changing the format in which time is being stored in table. If nothing else works out, I'll try your approach

Answer (score 0):

Basically i think you need the first available room_no to be assigned to your abc-xyz timespan. So, you should be fetching the first good value that is not in the already-booked set.
Example query could be something like this

```
select room_no
  from
  bookings
  where
  room_no not in (
    select
    room_no
    from bookings
    where start_time >= 'abc' and end_time <='xyz'
  )
  limit 1
```

Comment: Not really. It's upto the user who is preparing the timetable to assign the room. So it's not a case of first available room. He can choose any room he wants. Thus I'm trying to exclude that room from the dropdown list so that he just can't select it.

Comment: Well, in this case the answer should be contained in there: removing the limit clause you get every available room for the abc,xyz arguments passed in, than you can work them as you please